# Как вывести целое без пробелов

Tags: c++

Необходимо вывести в файловый поток таблицу. Целые числа при этом форматируются с пробелами. Как это отключить, у меня разделитель колонок - пробел.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    auto file = std::wofstream("table.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunс);

    for(const auto & line : getLines())
    {
        for(const auto & value : line)
        {
            file << L' ' << value;
        }
        file << L'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пример строки из 4 колонок {целое, строка, целое, вещественное}, первая колонка имеет тип `INT64` (`signed __int64`):

> 1 235 346 563 356 523 234 готов 43 0.5903

Comment: Небось русская (или немецкая, например) локаль?

Comment: Попробуйте так в начале программы: `std::locale::global(std::locale("C")); std::cout.imbue(std::locale());`.

Comment: Впрочем, если вы выводите строки, то пробел как разделитель — не самая хорошая идея: строки могут сами содержать пробелы. Но это уже другая проблема. Вам стоит подумать о каком-то более высокоуровневом формате, например, CSV.

Comment: @VladD не от меня зависит формат, требования такие

Comment: А установка локали помогла?

Comment: @VladD не помогла, теперь почему-то в файле отсутвуют строки с русскими символами, то есть файл пустой почти

Comment: Ох. Но числа в порядке?

Comment: А это ведь лишь абстрактный пример кода, а то там какой-то `std::ios::trunk` (последняя буква), да и двойной `getLines()` тоже смущает?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ага

Comment: @VladD Под "строками" я имею в виду строки таблицы, а не поля-строки. Срань какая-то нездоровая, возможно это "виЧерниЙ коД", то есть офтоп-опечатка.

Comment: Можно попробовать преобразовать в строку и там убрать пробелы

Comment: @AlexsandrTer Я вообще-то так и сделал уже, но вопрос не про как обойти, а про как отключить.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale.h

Comment: @Cerbo: Но всё же, с C-локалью **числа** выводятся правильно?

Comment: Пример кода не совсем удачный. Зачем тут какой-то 'getLines', если проблема в выводе числа? Может число уже считывается не как одно целое, а разбитое на части как видно при выводе?